# computer_move() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)?

Tags: python, arguments

```
import random
#these will be the positions the computer will take
new = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
null = ''
#string for the player
player = ''
#string for the computer
computer = ''
```

Here we define the two teams, the user(`player`) and the computer.

```
    def teams(player, computer):
    #asks the user to pick their character
    player = raw_input("Pick a team. X or O")
    #checking to make sure the character they enter is valid
    while player not in ('x', 'X', 'o', 'O'):
        #if not, prompt them to enter something else
        print "Please enter a valid character."
        player = raw_input("Pick a team. X or O")
    #set players character to x if chosen   
    if player == 'x' or player == 'X':
        print "Great, your team is X."
        #sets computers to o as default
        computer = 'o'
    #set players character to o
    else:
        print "Great, your team is O."
        #sets computers to x as default
        computer = 'x'
    #turn the characters to uppercase, easier to see
    return player.upper(), computer.upper()


#deciding whether the player or computer goes first 
def choose_turn():
    turn = None
    #checking if the answer entered is valid
    while turn not in ('y', 'Y', 'n', 'N'):
        #if not, prompt user for another input
        turn  = raw_input("Would you like to go first? Y or N")
        #sets user to go first
        if turn == 'y' or turn == 'Y':
            return 1
        #sets computer to go first
        elif turn == 'n' or turn == 'N':
            return 0
        #tells user if they have entered an incorrect answer
        else:
            print "Invalid choice"


#initially draws the board on the screen
def draw_board(a):
    print "\n\t", a[0], "|", a[1], "|", a[2]
    print "\t", "--------"
    print "\n\t", a[3], "|", a[4], "|", a[5]
    print "\t", "--------"
    print "\n\t", a[6], "|", a[7], "|", a[8], "\n"


#celebration message for the user
#lets them know they have won the game  
def celly_player():
    print "Whooohoo! You won!"


#celebration message for the computer
#lets the user know they have lost the game
def celly_computer():
    print "Hahaha, I won!"


#for when the user goes first in the game   
def player_first(player, computer, new):
    #has the player move if the game has not been won
    while win(player, computer, new) is None:
        move = player_move(player, new)
        new[int(move)] = player
        draw_board(new)
        if win(player, computer, new) != None:
            break
        else:
            pass
        print "okay, I'll take..."
        move_c = computer_move(player, computer, new)
        print move_c
        new[int(move_c)] = computer
        draw_board(new)
    #settin up the wins
    y = win(player, computer, new)
    #initiate user's winning message
    if y == 1:
        celly_player()
    #initiate computer's winning message
    elif y == 0:
        celly_computer()
    #tells the user that nobody has one, it is a tie
    else:
        print "Well...it's a tie. Cats!"


#for when the computer goes first in the game       
def computer_first(player, computer, new):
    #computer gets to move if the game has not been won
    while not win(player, computer, new):
        print "now I'll take..."
        move_c = computer_move(player, computer, new)
        print move_c
        new[move_c] = computer
        draw_board(new)
        if win(player, computer, new) != None:
            break
        else:
            pass
        move = computer_move(player, new)
        new[int(move)] = player
        draw_board(new)
    #settin up the wins
    y == win(player, computer, new)
    #initiates user's winning message
    if y == 1:
        celly_player()
    #initiates computer's winning message
    elif y == 0:
        celly_computer()
    #tells the user that nobody has one, it is a tie
    else:
        print "Well, it's a tie. Cats!"


#here we are setting up and defining the winning messages       
def win(player, computer, new):
    #combinations for winning positions
    rows = ((0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8), (0,3,6), (1,4,7), (2,5,8), (0,4,8), (2,4,6))
    for i in rows:
        if new[i[0]] == new[i[1]] == new[i[2]] != null:
            champ = new[i[0]]
            if champ == player:
                return 1
            elif champ == computer:
                return 0
            if null not in new:
                return "Tie game!"
    if null not in new:
        return "Tie game!"
    return None


#setting up moves for the player
def player_move(player, new):
    #prompts user for input
    a = raw_input("Where would you like to move?")
    while True:
        #checking if entered position is on the board
        if a not in('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'):
            #if not, prompts for a new position
            print "Please enter a valid move on the board."
            a = raw_input("Where would you like to move?")
        elif new[int(a)] != null:
            #lets user know their chosen space is unavailable
            print "Darn, this place has already been taken"
            #prompts for a new position
            a = raw_input("Where would you like to move?")
        else:
            return int(a)


#setting up moves for the user  
#using random numbers/positions     
def computer_move(computer, new):
    #best choices for computer to move
    best = [4, 0, 2, 6, 8]
    empty = []
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if new[i] == null:
            empty.append(i)
    for i in empty:
        new[i] = computer
        if win(player, computer, new) is 0:
            return i
        new[i] = null
    for i in empty:
        new[i] = player
        if win(player, computer, new) is 1:
            return i
        new[i] = null
    return int(blank[random.randrange(len(empty))])


#printing out the instructions to the user  
def instructions():
    print
    """
    Welcome to Python Tic Tac Toe!
    Make your move by entering a number 0-8. The board positions are
    shown below.
    0 | 1 | 2
    ---------
    3 | 4 | 5
    ---------
    6 | 7 | 8
    Best of luck!
    """


#main function  
def main(player, computer, new):
    instructions()
    #prompt user to start
    print "Let's get started!"
    a = teams(player, computer)
    player = a[0]
    computer = a[1]
    b = choose_turn()
    #player going first
    if b == 1:
        print "You are first."
        print "Let's start with a new board."
        draw_board(new)
        player_first(player, computer, new)
    #computer going first
    elif b == 0:
        print "I can be first"
        print "Let's start."
        draw_board(new)
        computer_first(player, computer, new)
    else:
        pass


main(player, computer, new)
raw_input("Please press enter to exit the game")
```

Comment: The error message should be pretty explanatory. You've defined `computer_move` to take 2 arguments, but you tried to call it with 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `computer_first` and `player_first` functions you are trying to call `computer_move` with three arguments:

```
move_c = computer_move(player, computer, new)
```

But the function has been defined as:

```
def computer_move(computer, new):
```

So it can only be called with two arguments, not three.